# Whats wrong with my database connection file?

Tags: php, mysql, database

The output of code is :

> Connected and SQL Problem

Which means that it connects but the desired databse i.e malala is not being selected.Please help?

```
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die("Connection Problem" . mysqli_connect_error($con));
  echo "Connected and ";
  $database = mysqli_select_db($con,malala) or die("SQL Problem".mysqli_connect_error($con));
  echo "Selected";
```

Comment: Ummm.  Is that your password?

Comment: @abracadaver this password is generated by Mysql Databases in Cpanel

Comment: Change line 3 to `$database = mysqli_select_db($con,'malala') or die("SQL Problem".mysqli_error($con));` and see if that outputs something different.

Comment: Hi the database name method was right with or without double/single quotes.It works either ways.The problem was that the Mysql admin panel in Cpanel prefixed the name of my database with the my username i.e 'savehand' and it became savehand_malala whereas i kept using malala.

Comment: yes i am a big douchebag to not check this in beginning :)

Comment: If you were using the wrong username, how does it output "Connected"? That doesn't make any sense at all. Also on another note, you are using `mysqli_connect_error` instead of `mysqli_error` when selecting your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, `malala` in `($con,malala)` needs to be quoted. It's being treated as a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

I.e.:

```
($con, "malala")
```

Or place it inside

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "savehand_tallal", "&aBE+9NxZ6^c")
```

as

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "savehand_tallal", "&aBE+9NxZ6^c", "malala")
```

so you won't need to use

```
$database = mysqli_select_db($con,malala)...
```

Having used error reporting though, would have thrown you an undefined constant malala notice.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Reference for `mysqli_connect()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Also make sure that the `malala` database was indeed created and doesn't hold any whitespace or foreign characters.

Comment: I have tried this already before finally posting my problem here.Its not working either way.

Comment: @TallalHassan make sure you've a webserver/PHP/MySQL installed and that they're all running and properly configured.

Comment: How da heck did you get so many points? I remember I was once ahead of you haha.

Comment: @Mike hehehe I remember that too Mike. I hope you've been well :-) well, let's just say that I have a bit too much time on hands sometimes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I hear ya. Take care, bud!

Comment: @Mike Thanks Mike, you too. *Cheers*

Comment: @TallalHassan in your password `&aBE+9NxZ6^c` the `&` and `^` characters may also be an issue here. I'm not 100% sure, but I have seen in some rare cases that in using characters as such, have an adverse effect. Double check all your configurations. There isn't much else to my answer/comments that I can add. Check for errors with error reporting to see if that yields additional errors/notices/warnings.

Comment: This answer based on the OP's original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33507104/1 should they modify their question.

Comment: @Fred everything is fine this password is generated by 'Mysql Databases' app in Cpanel.No latest errors are showing up in error logs.